# Error '1004' Unable to get the sum property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the above error for this line of code and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
Worksheets("BEL CFs").Range("F" & CFcounter + 5).Value = _
     WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet7.Range("F2:F" & CFcounter))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess it that you have cells in the sum range that are errors; `#N/A`,`#DIV/0`,...

Comment: If `CFcounter` is `0`, that will blow up. need more context.

Comment: My comment doesn't address your actual problem, but you might be able to handle the error more gracefully by using `Application.Sum()`, assigning the result to a `variant` type variable, then testing with `iserror` or `isnumeric` -- possibly.